# How to remove a subarray of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

How can I `remove a group of elements inside an array`?

I have the following code:

```
private void processResponse(byte[] response)
    {            
        byte[] header;
        byte[] payload;

        if (response.Length > 8)
        {
            header = response.Take<byte>(8).ToArray();
            //payload = //should be the rest of "response" bytes
        }           
    }
}
```

How can I make `payload` to be `response` without `header`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

```
payload = response.Skip(8).ToArray();
```

Comment: It is a good solution, but i would also like to remove the "skipped" part from the "main" array.
The best of the best would be a method like "String.Substring(..)" that also removes that substring, but for Arrays, or a Linq similar approach.
Thanks anyway!